# Unable to change php cURL timeout

Tags: php, curl, timeout, codeigniter-3

Currently i'm using php 5.6 with framework CodeIgniter. Also, i'm using cURL to hit Rest API

I try to change network timeout to 1000 second (just to test). But network time out is always +- 100 seconds.

[Network Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w5y8.png)

1. Try to change php time limit

   set_time_limit(0);
2. Try to add header

   header("Connection: Keep-Alive");
   header("Keep-Alive: timeout=1000, max=1000");
3. Try to add curl_timeout and curl_timeout_ms

   try {
   $link = "";

   ```
                if($data == "") {
                    $link = $url;
                }else {
                    $link = $url.$data;
                }
                $ch =   curl_init();

                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->session->userdata['api_loc']['idceco'].$link);
                        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                                    'Authorization: Bearer '. $this->session->userdata['session']['token'])
                                );
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000000);
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                if(curl_errno($ch))
            {
                echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
            }
                $json = json_decode($result);
                if($json->message == "Invalid access, token expired. AuthenticatedFalse") {
                    //redirect('Signin/logout');
                    return "Invalid access, token expired. AuthenticatedFalse";
                }else {
                    return $json;
                }
            }catch(Exception $e) {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
   ```

Try 3 of them but nothing works.  Is there any other reason why network timeout is not changing?

**EDIT**

Try to change curlopt_timeout to 10, 20, 50 seconds Working. But if it's more than 100 seconds. It's not working

Comment: Look for the `default_socket_timeout` option in the `php.ini`

Comment: @DylanDelobel default_ is set to 60 both local and master value in php.ini

Comment: @DylanDelobel Nothing change after ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 1000)